# How to do a self join in laravel resulting in distinct values

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

```
ID|user_id   |book_id   |author
1 |8         |7         |bill
2 |8         |6         |sally
3 |3         |7         |rob
4 |3         |4         |sarah
5 |3         |6         |jane
6 |8         |7         |frank
```

What I want to achieve are rows that user_id 8 book_ids match that of user_id 3 book_id. but only user_8s rows selected. And also distinct by book_id. So i want the result to be:

row 1,
row 2

So far I have this but unfortunately I keep getting row 6 as well as row 2 and row 1.  Basically i want the result to be distinct by book_id but im unsure how to do this.

```
$check = DB::table('table as u1') 
->join('table as u2','u1.book_id', '=', 'u2.book_id')
->where('u2.user_id', 8)->where('u1.user_id', 3)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options. You can use `distinct()` or `groupBy()`

Variant 1:

```
$check = DB::table('table as u1')
    ->join('table as u2','u1.book_id', '=', 'u2.book_id')
    ->where('u2.user_id', 8)->where('u1.user_id', 3)
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Variant 2:

```
$check = DB::table('table as u1')
    ->join('table as u2','u1.book_id', '=', 'u2.book_id')
    ->where('u2.user_id', 8)->where('u1.user_id', 3)
    ->groupBy('u1.book_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I thought it might be groupBy (Variant 2) but for some reason I get only row 1. Variant 1 I get rows 1, 2, and 6.

Comment: @Billy changed the group by from user_id to u1.book_id

Answer (score 0):

A proper (compatible with other databases and working with [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) enabled, which is on by default in MySQL 5.7) equivalent MySQL query to get the desired result is

```sql
SELECT t.*
  FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(t1.id) id
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
      ON t1.book_id = t2.book_id
   WHERE t1.user_id = 8
     AND t2.user_id = 3
   GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.book_id  
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
```

Output:

```
| ID | user_id | book_id | author |
|----|---------|---------|--------|
|  1 |       8 |       7 |   bill |
|  2 |       8 |       6 |  sally |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/472c7/12)** demo

Using Laravel Query Builder it will look like this

```php
$subquery = DB::table('table as t1')
    ->join('table as t2', 't1.book_id', '=', 't2.book_id')
    ->where('t1.user_id', 8)
    ->where('t2.user_id', 3)
    ->groupBy(['t1.user_id', 't1.book_id'])
    ->select(DB::raw('MIN(t1.id) as id'));
$check = DB::table('table as t')
    ->join(DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()}) as q"), 't.id', '=', 'q.id')
    ->mergeBindings($subquery)
    ->select(['t.id', 't.user_id', 't.book_id', 't.author'])
    ->get();
```